# cant translate text with value using GETX in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, flutter-getx

the problem is that the text has value which declares the day before the text
so idk how to translate this text that includes value.

```
  untilEventDay =
                      '${pDate.difference(DateTime.now()).inDays},days/ until event day'
                          .tr;
```

in translation page :

```
,days/ until next event day': 'ڕؤژ ماوه‌/ تاوه‌كو ئیڤێنتی داهاتوو',
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should separate the value's string from your translation

```
var eventDayCountDownTitle = '${pDate.difference(DateTime.now()).inDays}' + ',' + days/ until event day'.tr;
```

and if you need your day number to be in a specific language, you can use a map or a helper method. map solution would be something like this:

```
Map<String,String> englishToPersianNumber = {'1' : '۱'}
```

and then use it in your string :

```
englishToPersianNumber[pDate.difference(DateTime.now()).inDays.toString()]
```

**Important**: to have a cleaner code, you can create a helper method to generate your desired string, and call it in your text widget. the code would be more understandable that way. **Also, you can add handle any conditions that may later be added to the string generator. like if it's the last day, write something else instead of 0 days remaining.**

```
    String eventDayCountDownTitle(int remainingDays) {
if(remainingDays == 0) return "Less than One day to the event".tr;
    return '${remainingDays.toString}' + ',' + 'days/ until event day'.tr;
    }
```

ps. your question's title is wrong, you should change it to what you're explaining in the caption

Comment: ohh , why i didn't try that , thank u so much , yea i did for the remaining day , it was just a piece of the code , 

that was my first post , i'd try to match the title next time , thanks again ^^

Comment: good! have fun coding!